# A basic question on Current Flow, Voltage, and Power consumption

Tags: voltage, power, current, resistance, current-measurement

**Background:**

Assume that I have Bulb that consumes **10 watts** of electrical energy (power).
The operating values for full brightness are: 5 volts, and 2 amps.
Since **Power(p) = Voltage(V) x Current(I) = 5 x 2 = 10 watts**

**Question**:

For a bulb to glow all it cares for is the **flow of electrons at the required rate (amps)** --> call it **axiom**.
In the above circuit, **assume that I keep the current constant at 2 amps by reducing both the voltage and resistance**.

So, by my **axiom**, I expect the same brightness of the bulb, **but the bulb glows at lower brightness**.
I know the lower brightness is because of **lower power since voltage is reduced**, but by my **axiom**: "For a bulb to glow all it cares for is the **flow of electrons at the required rate (amps)",  shouldn't the bulb remain bright?**

Or, is my **axiom** wrong?

**Edit**: As many of you have mentined, I accept that usage of the word **axiom** is wrong in this context.
I would rather use the word **assumption**, however, since many answers to this questions refers to the word **axiom**, I do not want to change it to **assumption**, as this would confuse future readers. Thanks.

Comment: no brightness is about heat dissipated hence energy. heat is all about power I^2 *R. you keep I constant but decrease R. your intuition is wrong. (that's why they sell bulbs regarding their wattage to relate it to brightness)

Comment: @user16307 It doesn't matter. It won't work even in case of ideal 100% efficient bulbs.

Comment: @EugeneSh. do you agree that more photons are ejected with increasing thermal energy?

Comment: The Light-bulb is non-linear device. Also how you want to change the resistance without changing the physical properties of the bulb? Also if the current is kept constant then the voltage across any device is I*R.

Comment: @user16307 I do not agree that thermal energy is necessary at all to emit photons.

Comment: @EugeneSh. examples of thermal radiation include the visible light and infrared light emitted by an incandescent light bulb, the infrared radiation emitted by animals and detectable with an infrared camera, and the cosmic microwave background radiation.

Comment: @user16307 Which is supporting my point :) Suppose that we can "see" the whole spectrum radiated. What I am trying to say, that even in that case the **Axiom** will be false.

Comment: "An axiom or postulate as defined in classic philosophy, is a statement (in mathematics often shown in symbolic form) that is so evident or well-established, that it is accepted without controversy or question." So please remove the word axiom in your question, makes me angry.

Comment: You have all well addressed my question, thanks.
@MarkoBuršič, I accept that usage of the word "axiom" is wrong in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a bulb to glow all it cares for is the flow of electrons at the required rate (amps).

Correct, if the filament gauge remains constant.

> Assume that I keep the current constant at 2 amps by reducing both the voltage and resistance.

Reducing the voltage isn't a problem. Reducing the resistance is because you need to shorten the filament length.

If you could make a filament lamp with variable length filament you would get **constant brightness per unit length**. Total brightness would, of course, drop. Try it and see ...

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhfdl5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. 'Bulb' with variable filament length.*

In Figure 1 we've created a lamp with variable filament length. You can adjust the filament resistance by switching out lamps as you step down the voltage.

> "For a bulb to glow all it cares for is the flow of electrons at the required rate (amps)", shouldn't the bulb remain bright?

Yes, the filament temperature will remain the same, the light spectrum emitted will be the same and the light emitted per unit length will be the same. There will just be less of it overall.

Comment: "the light emitted will be the same. There will just be less of it." i think it is better to say "the light emitted per unit filament will be the same" imao

Comment: I meant to write "... and the light _spectrum_ emitted will be the same." Thank you.

Comment: @transistor Thanks, you have answered the question comprehensively. The simulation really helped.

Answer (score 1):

Don't invent **Axioms**, as anything you can come up on this level is already invented before you. It can be simply answered in terms of energy conservation, but I'll give you the intuition. By reducing the resistance you have changed the physical properties of the bulb. Like, for instance, the length or the thickness of the filament wire in it. Thus reducing the working area and/or the number of photon generating atoms (roughly speaking).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, usage of the word **axiom** is wrong in this context, I have amended my question.